# Trouble setting checkbox ON by default in IE7 and IE8 with Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a google map (API 3) that is displaying KML files and I have created a function that allows them to be toggled on or off via a control panel with checkboxes. The checkboxes are by default checked when the page loads, but this is not working in IE7 or IE8. I can't figure out why. I have tried adding

```
object.defaultChecked = true;
```

to each of the variables, but this isn't working. I have also tried adding this javascript, but it is also not working...

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
  if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

Is there some mystery to how IE7-IE8 handles checkboxes in the DOM? Any help is appreciated!

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
function createTogglers() {

var html = "<form><ul>";
for (var prop in kml) {
    html += "<li class='selected'><span id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
    " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/></span>" +
    kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
}
html += "<\/ul><\/form>";

document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
}


function removeAll() {
for (var prop in kml) {
    if (kml[prop].obj) {
        kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
        delete kml[prop].obj;
    }

}
}


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected: normal);
}

function startup() { 
var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
checkit.checked = true; // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit.setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit.checked = 'checked'; // Does not work in IE 7-8
toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
highlight(checkit, 'selector-a');

var checkit2 = document.getElementById('b');
checkit2.checked = true; // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit2.setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit2.checked = 'checked'; // Does not work in IE 7-8
toggleKML(checkit2, 'b');
highlight(checkit2, 'selector-b');

var checkit3 = document.getElementById('c');
checkit3.checked = true; // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit3.setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit3.checked = 'checked'; // Does not work in IE 7-8
toggleKML(checkit3, 'c');
highlight(checkit3, 'selector-c');

var checkit4 = document.getElementById('d');
checkit4.checked = true; // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit4.setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit4.checked = 'checked'; // Does not work in IE 7-8
toggleKML(checkit4, 'd');
highlight(checkit4, 'selector-d');

var checkit5 = document.getElementById('e');
checkit5.checked = true; // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit5.setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); // Does not work in IE 7-8
checkit5.checked = 'checked'; // Does not work in IE 7-8
toggleKML(checkit5, 'e');
highlight(checkit5, 'selector-e');
```

Comment: The example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112502/cant-get-kml-files-to-load-on-start-or-location-search-to-work-in-custom-map) works for me  in IE.

Comment: I cant help you, sorry - It works on IE7, IE8 and IE9 here. Deleted my answer. There is differences in the loading, like zoom, but the checkboxes works very well.

Comment: So the checkboxes are checked in IE7 and IE8 when the page loads for you?

Comment: geocodezip - your example solved this issue for me. Thank you both for your input.